# Something like models for class in PHP

Tags: php

I want to describe you what I want to make. I'm making my own framework and for each view (ie. `http://localhost/admin/article/images/1`) it will call new class `ArticleController()` in folder `admin/article` and then cal function `images()` with arguments, in this example `id = 1`.

This is working perfectly, but now I want to make my framework much easier to read. For example `ArticleController` has a lot of functions, because you can make new articles, edit them, remove, add images, change categories... etc and file is becoming bigger and bigger. Now it has more than 520 lines of code and it is hard to read. What I want to make are something like models. So in the same directory, there can be file like `ModelImages` and it will contain functions such as `getImages` or `uploadImage` etc...

There can be more model files (`Model*.php`) and all of then should access `ArticleController` as their parent. I know, that I can do `class ModelImages extends ArticleController...` and then `new ModelImages()` instead of `new ArticleController()`, but what about other models?

Have you ever met with something like that? Or, is it even possible?

Comment: MVC doesnt work like that (or shouldnt do).  The Controller access the model, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the functionality of PHP Traits introduced in PHP 5.4.
They can contain functionalities you can inject into each class seamlessly.

Read more about them here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) for every slash in the URL. For instance, `/admin/article/images/1` might be processed by `Admin\Article\Images::callController()`. In this case the file system might look like `lib/Admin/Article/Images.php`.

There may be a root controller converting URI string to the classname. For example:

```php
namespace Admin\Article {
class Images {
  public function test() {echo __CLASS__;}
}
}

namespace {
class RootController {
  public static function getClassByUri($uri) {
    $uri_parts = explode('/', $uri);
    array_pop($uri_parts);

    $parts = [];
    foreach ($uri_parts as $part) {
      $parts[]= static::_toCamelCase($part);
    }

    $class = implode('\\', $parts);

    if (!class_exists($class)) {
      throw new \RuntimeException("Can not find class for uri $uri");
    }

    return $class;
  }

  private static function _toCamelCase($string) {
    return str_replace(' ', '',
      ucwords(preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]/', ' ', strtolower($string))));
  }
}


$uri = '/admin/article/images/1';
$class = RootController::getClassByUri($uri);
$obj = new $class();
$obj->test();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried @vuryss solution and it works.